# How do I save a Blender file?

Tags: documentation

I am going through the Blender 2.79b manual online here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/splash.html
I don't see my question answered in it.

I have Blender open on my Mac. I have imported an svg file. I can select the File Browser view. I can see the folder URL to the Blender folder on my filesystem. There is a text box under this. There is a file directory under it.

I can type a filename in the box under the folder URL box and hit enter, but am not sure if it is having any effect -- it's not showing up in the file listing.

How do I save this or any blend as a .blend file? I can't shut down Blender until I figure this out!

Comment: You're trying to save the blender project file right?

Comment: Make sure you have picked a spot to save the file that you can easily navigate to in Finder (like Documents) for starters. Pressing enter in the Blender filesystem window should save the file (and close the save dialogue) but you can also try clicking the button on the top right labelled "Save Blender File"

Comment: As with most software press Ctrl+S to save. A new window will open to navigate to wherever you want to save in your computer. You can specify the name the name of the file there.

Comment: Ctrl+S did the trick.  NOW I see the Save Blender File!

Comment: My second question: Why is a simple question like this being upvoted? Ha ha

Answer (score 2):

As with most software, the keyboard shortcut to [save](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/file.html?highlight=save#save-load) a file is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. A new window will open to navigate to wherever you want to save in your computer and specify the name the name of the file.

An alternative using the menu pressing file>save.

[image]